# Animating elements in a ContentControl's DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a `ContentControl` that I'm styling with a `DataTemplate`.  I'd like to be able to define an animation outside of the `ContentControl` that animates elements in the `DataTemplate`.  This XAML is a small, simplified example of my scenario:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StoryboardTesting.Stage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TheBlock1" Text="Foo!" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="TheBlock2" Text="Bar!" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup Name="ValueStates">
            <VisualState Name="ToState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyContentControl"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                     Duration="0:0:1"
                                     To="0" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState Name="FromState" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'd like the animation to be able to target either `TextBox` in the template (instead of "MyContentControl"), either by position or name.  I'm starting the animation in the `UserControl`'s code-behind with a call like this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this, "ToState", true);
```

When I run this (replacing "MyContentControl" with "TheBlock"), I get the following:

> InvalidOperationException:  'TheBlock1' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'StoryboardTesting.Stage'.

Which makes sense.  Is there a way to address either block using property names?  I need to avoid codebehind since this is XAML that is being generated at runtime.

Comment: Have you found out a solution for your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly suggest you to learn using Blend when working on WPF projects. While XAML by keyboard skills are indeed useful, Blend is also very helpful. It took me about 5 minutes to build the following example for you, it's a `DataTemplate` which has states.

(first I created an empty `DataTemplate`, then I edited in Blend)

User can press any of the 2 buttons on the bottom and the current state will be changed.

[image]
[image]

As you'll see below, behaviors proven to be really helpful for handling states, no code-behind at all.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:wpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication3:MyObject x:Key="MyObject1" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1" DataType="wpfApplication3:MyObject">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="37*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="13*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Red">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Green">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Lime" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Button x:Name="button"
                        Grid.RowSpan="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Width="100"
                        Height="100"
                        Margin="2"
                        Content="Button"
                        FontSize="26.667" />
                <Button Grid.Row="1"
                        Width="Auto"
                        Margin="2"
                        Content="State1">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Red" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
                <Button Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Width="Auto"
                        Margin="2"
                        Content="State2">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Green" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyObject1}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template1}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    internal class MyObject
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer the point of your question, those states belong to the `DataTemplate`; defining these states outside of it doesn't make any sense and as you've experienced it is not even possible, and this is for a good reason !

Imagine that you use this template in 2 different places, would they share the same state ? Of course no, so the states have to be defined inside it, not outside.

Comment: This doesn't address my question very well.  I'd like animations defined outside of a control to animate child controls inside of it (from a template).  This is already somewhat possible because you can use property navigation in storyboard property targets.  I was thinking I just couldn't figure out the property to get at the controls created by the template.

Comment: I think you are mis-understanding the problem, it is related to the type of object that contains the objects you are trying to access. A DataTemplate in this case is a resource, not an object that will **directly** be part of the visual tree of the object you are inside. While indeed you can access the elements as you are saying like in this example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx, you are simply mis-using how things were intended to be used. My answer addresses your question somewhat because you specified **no-code behind*.

Comment: How you are trying to access things is possible like in this example because it is a FrameworkElement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx but not for a DataTemplate. Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstate(v=vs.110).aspx. I can only recommend looking at Blend to see how MS have crafted the visual states of their controls :D